# Is there a way to prevent new console app projects from defaulting to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, console-application

In the New Project dialog of Visual Studio 2010, under Installed Templates->Visual C#... if I choose Console Application and make sure .NET Framework 4 is selected in the drop-down menu overhead, my new project defaults to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

Is there a way to force this to default to .NET Framework 4 instead of the client profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache\CSharp\Windows\1033\ConsoleApplication.zi‌​p\consoleapplication.csproj, remove `<TargetFrameworkProfile>`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can change it in the original templates without the use of black magic. If its really annoying for your, you can create a custom template based on the original ones, having the target framework set to the full framework. See the following link on how to create a new template based on an existing project [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185319.aspx)

Comment: Totally forgot about this, but it would probably work as well.

Answer (score -2):

.NET Framework 4 Client Profile is default for all Windows desctop applications. Windows Forms, Console, WPF

Comment: I won't down vote, but this doesn't really address the question.